# Button on jquery datepicker not setting values in ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have added 'Today' button in jquery date picker.When i click on this button it is showing today's value on UI but it is not setting value to ember data.

below is code.

```
function setupDatepickerButtons(input) {
      Ember.run.later(function() {
        var buttonPane = Ember.$(input)
          .datepicker("widget")
          .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
        buttonPane.find('.ui-datepicker-current').remove();
        Ember.$('<button>', {
          text: "Today",
          click: function() {
            Ember.$(visibleEl).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            Ember.$(visibleEl).datepicker('hide');
          }
        }).appendTo(buttonPane);
        buttonPane.find("button").removeClass().addClass('btn btn-default');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code) and listen to "change" event on input or corresponding event of plugin that you use.